# Interface as a Generic Parameter

Tags: java, generics, interface

For a `Map` by itself how come I can do

```
Map<Object, Object> map1 = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
```

But for a `Map` in a `Map`, I cannot do

```
Map<Object, Map<Object, Object>> map2 = new HashMap<Object, HashMap<Object, Object>>();
```

Instead, I must do

```
Map<Object, HashMap<Object, Object>> map3 = new HashMap<Object, HashMap<Object, Object>>();
```

This situation isn't exclusive to `Maps`, it also pertains to `Set` and I'm assuming all other interfaces.  In other words, I cannot use interfaces as Generics.  Why not?

Comment: Why not just do: `Map<Object, Map<Object, Object>> map2 = new HashMap<Object, Map<Object, Object>>();`?? This would work **and** would be much cleaner as it codes to the interface.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels hmm it's weird that's possible...I thought I have to implement interfaces (use `HashMap` instead of `Map` in the last part) when I instantiate.

Comment: There's nothing weird about it as it's in the *declaration* portion of the variable, even though it's on the right side, since you've not yet created Maps to go into that slot.